# Swagger AccessMode AUTO

Tags: swagger

ApiModelProperties can have an [AccessMode](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.X/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.AccessMode.html) specified as READ_ONLY, or READ_WRITE. But the default is AUTO.

How does AUTO decide which value it uses?